# Want a list box to show 1-10, but what is shown in the drop-down is dependent on another list item

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-forms

I want to create a Combo box (Combo Box B) on an Access form containing numbers 1-10.  In other words, the drop-down shows numbers 1-10 sequentially.

However, what is shown in the drop-down is dependent on Combo box A.

- If `x` shows in Combo Box A, items `1-10` should show in Combo Box B.
- If `y` shows in Combo Box A, numbers `1-5` should only show in Combo Box B, or at minimum prevent someone from selecting `6` or larger.
- If `z` shows in Combo Box A, nothing should be selectable in Combo Box B.

My coding skills are rusty as I've not done much in over 10 years.  Is this something easily achievable in Access, or will I need some VBA to assist?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your question isn't just a contrived example, and that you really want to display the integers `1-10` and `1-5` in your combobox, then in it's simplest form, you could use the following function evaluated on the `After Update` event of your combobox 'A' and on the `On Load` event of your form:

```vb
Function UpdateComboRowSource(cmbCom As ComboBox, ByVal strVal As String)
    cmbCom.RowSourceType = "Value List"
    Select Case LCase(strVal)
        Case "x":  cmbCom.RowSource = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10"
        Case "y":  cmbCom.RowSource = "1;2;3;4;5"
        Case Else: cmbCom.RowSource = ""
    End Select
End Function
```

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    UpdateComboRowSource ComboB, ComboA.Value
End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub ComboA_AfterUpdate()
    UpdateComboRowSource ComboB, ComboA.Value
End Sub
```